# ¿como ordenar una cadena con dos apellidos(primer y segundo apellidos? en español ( con tildes y ñ ) en php

Tags: php, ordenamiento

he usado usort con una función personalizada, que elimina las tildes y cualquier otra acentuación, el problema llega con las ñ, los apellidos compuestos y por tener los dos apellidos en la misma cadena. ¿alguna ayuda?

```
function callback($name1,$name2){
            //callback para poder ordenar existiendo tildes en el campo de ordenamiento.
            $patterns = array(
                'a' => '(á|à|â|ä|Á|À|Â|Ä)',
                'e' => '(é|è|ê|ë|É|È|Ê|Ë)',
                'i' => '(í|ì|î|ï|Í|Ì|Î|Ï)',
                'o' => '(ó|ò|ô|ö|Ó|Ò|Ô|Ö)',
                'u' => '(ú|ù|û|ü|Ú|Ù|Û|Ü)'
            );          
            $name1_t['apellidos'] = preg_replace(array_values($patterns), array_keys($patterns), $name1['apellidos']);
            $name2_t['apellidos'] = preg_replace(array_values($patterns), array_keys($patterns), $name2['apellidos']);          
            return strcasecmp($name1_t['apellidos'], $name2_t['apellidos']);
    }
```

Comment: Tu pregunta no es el del todo clara. Pon algunos ejemplos de los datos que los que estás trabajando, del resultado que obtienes y de lo que esperas obtener. Además, puede que esto pueda lograrse de una forma más sencilla, pero sin ver un escenario real es difícil poder ayudarte.

Comment: Tengo un array con los siguientes datos:

```$personas=array("Pérez López","Peña Maqueda","Llanes Ortega","López García","López-Herrera Andar")```

la salida correcta debería ser

Llanes Ortega
López García
López-Herrera Andar
Peña Maqueda
Pérez López

he probado con varios tipos de ordenaciones, con varios tipos de codificacionoes .. y no consigo la salida correcta

Comment: Faltan aspectos para entender tu pregunta: ¿se debe ordenar tomando en cuenta 1er y 2do apellido? Si es así, **¿de qué modo determinas cuál es el 1er y el 2do apellido?** Eso es fundamental para una respuesta o para remitir la solución a otro ámbito (el origen de los datos).

Comment: si por los dos apellidos, la única forma de determinar el primero del segundo es un espacio en blanco  la lista debería salir  "Llanes Ortega","López García", "López-Herrera Andar", "Peña Maqueda", "Pérez López"

Comment: No, **un espacio en blanco no es un criterio válido para determinar apellidos**. Bastan casos como `de los Monteros Pérez` o `García de Montesinos` o `De la Calle de al Lado`, para tener un grave problema. Creo que deberías remitirte al orígen de los datos (base de datos o lo que sea) para traer ya los apellidos diferenciados. De otro modo no veo que puedas resolver esto. Para mi el problema es ese, todo lo demás, una vez resuelto eso, será pan comido.

Comment: pues si .. tienes razón es un gran problema.. pero me los traigo importados de Google Classroom y no tengo forma de diferenciar 1 y 2 apellidos.

Comment: No conozco Google Classroom, pero debe haber alguna forma, sería cuestión de revisar la documentación.

Comment: esta es lo que ofrece ... es una aplicacion americana que solo tienen un apellido.  class Google_Service_Classroom_Name extends Google_Model
{
  public $familyName;
  public $fullName;
  public $givenName;

Comment: que raro... un simple `sort($personas)` esta devolviendo en el orden que esperas... no veo que te falta...

Comment: perdón era un ejemplo  ``$personas=array("Ager lópez","Álamo Sanchez","Pérez López","Peña Maqueda","Llanes Ortega","López García","López-Herrera Andar") ;

sort($personas);



for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($personas);$i++) {
  echo $personas[$i];
  echo "<br/>";
}``

Comment: No sé si estamos hablando de dos cosas distintas, por un lado, la diatriba de si un apellido o dos apellidos, y por otra el orden. En cuanto al orden, desde PHP 5.3 puedes usar [la clase `Collator`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.collator.php), haciendo simplemente esto: `$mCollator = new Collator('es_ES');
$mCollator->sort($personas);` de ese modo el array queda ordenado adecuadamente. Ahora bien, si necesita un orden por 1er apellido o por 2do apellido, volvemos a lo tratado en comentarios anteriores.

Comment: jajajajaja joder ... tan fácil como eso ... muchísimas gracias